# How to filter grep results

Tags: grep

I'm running this command on OS X to pull the logic board ID:

```
ioreg -l | grep board-id
```

which gives me this output:

```
|   "board-id" = <"Mac-FC02E91DDD3FA6A4">
```

The only part I'm interested in is the "Mac-FC02E91DDD3FA6A4". Is there a way to filter the results from grep to only show me this part? OR is there a second step I could do to clean up the grep results?

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` you can do this

```
ioreg -l | awk -F\" '/board-id/ {print $4}
Mac-FC02E91DDD3FA6A4
```

This search for `board-id`, divide output by `"` and then print part `4`

Answer (score 0):

```
ioreg -l | grep "board-id" | cut -d \" -f 4
```

Answer (score 0):

one way still with grep, try this line:

```
ioreg -l|grep -Po 'board-id".*<"\K[^"]*'
```